# Open file knowing only a part of its name

Tags: python, naming

I'm currently reading a file and importing the data in it with the line:

```
# Read data from file.
data = np.loadtxt(join(mypath, 'file.data'), unpack=True)
```

where the variable `mypath` is known. The issue is that the file `file.data` will change with time assuming names like:

```
file_3453453.data
file_12324.data
file_987667.data
...
```

So I need a way to tell the code to open the file in that path that has a name like `file*.data`, assuming that there will always be only *one* file by that name in the path. Is there a way to do this in `python`?

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple files with that name?

Comment: There will always be only one file by that name in that path. Sorry I didn't make that explicit, I'll update the question now.

Comment: So, crash and burn? I know it's inconvenient, but you should at least know what happens if such an assumption is broken. Because it *will* be broken.

Comment: Haha ok, I'm pretty sure it won't because I'm the one putting that file there but if it happens that I forget and two files with the same name convention are in the path then the code should crash to remind me to *pay attention*. Really, that's all I need.

Comment: Then just renaming it at the time you put it there might be give you that reminder sooner and simplify the code.

Comment: Yes delnam I know but I was asking for help on how to do that particular thing with python, not on how I should do my coding/workflow. I see a number of answers have been added so thanks anyway for your concern.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `glob` module. It allows pattern matching on filenames and does exactly what you're asking

```
import glob

for fpath in glob.glob(mypath):
    print fpath
```

e.g I have a directory with files named google.xml, google.json and google.csv.

I can use glob like this:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('g*gle*')
['google.json', 'google.xml', 'google.csv']
```

Note that `glob` uses the `fnmatch` module but it has a simpler interface and it matches paths instead of filenames only.

You can search relative paths and don't have to use `os.path.join`. In the example above if I change to the parent directory and try to match file names, it returns the relative paths:

```
>>> import os
>>> import glob
>>> os.chdir('..')
>>> glob.glob('foo/google*')
['foo/google.json', 'foo/google.xml', 'foo/google.csv']
```

Comment: This seems like a good answer but does it allow to set the end part of the file to match the pattern `file*.data` or does it only make use of the first part of the filename? Sp's answer using `fnmatch` can do what I'm talking about.

Comment: glob uses fnmatch, so it also matches other patterns like file*.data. I've edited the answer to show that

Answer (score 5):

Also check out [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html):

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> import os
>>>
>>> fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('.'), 'file_*.data')
['file_3453453.data']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I simple solution would be to use the python modules "os" and "re":

```
import os
import re
for file in os.listdir(mypath):
     if re.match("file_\d+\.data", file):
     ...
```

Comment: You need to escape the `.` in your pattern.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Fixed. Without escaping, the code would have matched also files with names like - "file_123data". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import os

[os.path.join(root, f) for root, _, files in os.walk(mypath)
                       for f in files
                       if f.startswith('file') and f.endswith('.data')]
```

It'll return a list of all files `file*.data`, in case there are more than one. You can just iterate through them. If there is only one file, then just put `[0]` at then end of the list comprehension.