# Rename a file with a pattern

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a filename that looks like

```
er-log-0.0.1-20150807.194034-8.jar
```

The format it follows is like

```
artifactId-version-timestamp.jar
```

I want to rename this to `artifactId.jar`.

I tried

```
>>> fname = "er-log-0.0.1-20150807.194034-8.jar"
>>> import os
>>> os.rename("er-log*", "er-log.jar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The file is in the current directory though

Comment: Are you attempting to rename every file that matches your pattern in a certain directory?

Comment: There is just one, and will be one always, its a maven artifact

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open file knowing only a part of its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433177/open-file-knowing-only-a-part-of-its-name) -- this shows a lot of ways to get a file name when you only know part of it. You can use these answers to get to the point where you simply call `os.rename` rather than `open`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) if you want to find all the files using a shell wildcard:

```
import os
from glob import glob
path = "/path_to_files"

f = glob(os.path.join(path,"er-log*"))[0]
os.rename(f, os.path.join(path,"er-log.jar"))
```

Using `"er-log*"` with os.rename, python is looking for a file actually called `"er-log*"`.
         If you run the code from the same directory, you don't need to join the path, just  `os.rename(f, "er-log.jar")`

Comment: @JakeGriffin, yep, actually turns out they only want one file

Comment: @JakeGriffin, what do you think `"er-log*"` is doing in the OPs code?

Comment: @JakeGriffin, `-0.0.1` changes not the `er-log` as per the OPs own code, this is doing exactly what is asked and what the OP is trying to do using rename

Comment: @JakeGriffin, what question are you referring to?

Comment: @JakeGriffin, the OP is trying to match a file using part of a filename with a wildcard using rename which is not possible. I have explained why it does not work which is what the OP is asking and how to get their example input to work. If the OP wants more then they will have to provide more information as I am not a mind reader.  You have your downvote in so end of discussion

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
direc = "C:\\"
for file in next(os.walk(direc))[2]:
    if file.endswith(".jar"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(direc, file), os.path.join(direc, "artifactId.jar"))
    break
```

Change c:\ to your wanted path :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would accomplish your end, in a user-friendly sort of way.

Notes:

- I rely upon the user to specify the filename, using wildards if he likes.
- I use the `re` module to both determine if the passed-in filename matches your pattern and to extract the root of the filename.

Typical use cases:

```
# This one is particularly useful if the user has tab expansion
# in his shell. Tab expasion makes it easy to specify
# a single file name.
python rename_artifact.py er-log-0.0.1-20150807.194034-8.jar

# Or the user can glob the filename. "-n" and "-v" make it 
# easy to see what the script would do/actually does. 
python -n *.jar
python -v *.jar
```

Code:

```
import argparse
import re
import os


# Take a passed-in arg, confirm it matches
# the pattern, and add the new file name
def artifact(old_filename):
    # Adjust regular expression to taste
    result = re.match('(.*)-[0-9.]+-\d+\.\d+-\d+(\.jar)', old_filename)
    if not result:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
            "bad file name: {}".format(old_filename))
    new_filename = ''.join(result.groups())
    return old_filename, new_filename

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Rename files to avoid timestamps')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--dry-run',
                    action='store_true',
                    help="Don't actually run any commands; just print them.")
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='Verbosely list the files processed')
parser.add_argument(
    'FILE',
    help='File name, like er-log-0.0.1-20150807.194034-8.jar',
    nargs='+',
    type=artifact)
args = parser.parse_args()

for rename in args.FILE:
    if args.dry_run or args.verbose:
        print 'rename({},{})'.format(*rename)
    if not args.dry_run:
        os.rename(*rename)
```