# Merging PDFs based on a value in the file name

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a folder of a hundreds of pdfs that I need to make into a single PDF based on a unique id in the name.

The pdfs are name in this format '_UniqueID_Series.pdf'
example:

- _9424_01.pdf
- _9424_02.pdf
- _9424_03.pdf
- _9425_01.pdf
- _9425_02.pdf
- _9426_01.pdf

I need to name the output based on the Unique ID and include the all in that series (in order) so my output for this example will have 3 pdfs: 9424.pdf (3pages) 9425.pdf (2 pages) 9426.pdf (1 page)

I am able to use PyPDF2 to append all pdfs in a folder into one. but I'm too new with python to figure out how to group these based on the unique ID. Is this possible to do in python? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous approaches to solve this problem, here's how I would go about it.

If you extract the files based on the descending values of their name, you will then get their names in the series given above. This will yield a list which you can then use it to iterate through the file names. See this - [Open file knowing only a part of its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433177/open-file-knowing-only-a-part-of-its-name)

Following that simply iterate through the files, e.g.

```
Files = [_9424_01.pdf,_9424_02.pdf] #example list. You will obtain in this form  from the above step.
prev = " "# to check what the prev file name was
for file in Files: 
   if file == prev or prev == " ": #the latter is True in the first instance
      #use PyPDF2  to create the pdfs for that id
   else:   
      #Differnt file name, so create a new pdf for this.
   prev = file
```

To extract the middle number of the file for example `9424` from `_9424_01.pdf` use a `regex` or `split()` method, e.g.

```
file = "_9424_01.pdf"
UniqID = file.split("_")[1]
print(UniqID) #Gives 9424
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You have given me lots of good info here. I will get back to you after i work through this.

Comment: @Bobarmntrt Great to hear. If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information. And feel free to ask if you have any questions

Comment: I feel like you have given me everything i need, but im too much of a noob with pyton to put it all together. I have loaded a list from all the pdfs using files = glob.glob(*.pdf) but I'm stuck on getting the Iteration and PyPDF2 append to work .

Comment: I see. If you can append your new problem to the question or if you feel if its too broad, or a new topic ask it as a new question

Comment: Not yet, sill trying to get it figured out.